# Passively prevent "Thank you in advance" in questions/comments

Tags: feature-request, edits, suggested-edits, comment-flags, quality-filter

I've edited and flagged a lot of questions and comments. Most often to remove "Thank you", "Thanks in advance", etc. One is actively encouraged to remove this fluff ([Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)).

Why not notifying users that writing "Thank you" is not necessary? My idea: Whenever someone writes "Thank you" in a question or comment, a bubble could show up saying that it's not necessary, maybe with a link to a site explaining the etiquette on the SE network.

This could prevent a lot of work and take load off from the moderators.